# Redux Form Initialize Form from State

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Hi I cant wrap my head around initializing redux form. My form has templates. When user selects template, the action is dispatched and I save the selected template as `activeTemplate` in my redux state. Then I would like to every time this `activeTemplate` changes to reinitialize the form. My code goes like this:

```
MainForm = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MainForm);

MainForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'main',
  // Here I would like to use the activeTemplate from redux store
  initialValues: {travelers: [{name: 'Lada'}, {name: 'Pepa'}]},
  enableReinitialize: true,
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(MainForm);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    formValues: state.form.main.values,
    formTemplates: state.templates.templates,
    activeTemplate: state.templates.activeTemplate,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ getTemplates, activateTemplate }, dispatch);
}

export default MainForm;
```

Im not sure how to pass the `activeTemplate` to `initialValues` properly. I already have some 'hardcoded' `initialValues` when the form loads, because there is no `activeTemplate` yet. The code may need some refactor in order to make this work, because I dont see how to make this work at this state. I appreciate any help!

```
import { GET_TEMPLATES, ACTIVATE_TEMPLATE } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TEMPLATES:
      return {
        templates: action.payload
      }
    case ACTIVATE_TEMPLATE:
      return {
        ...state, activeTemplates: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `activeTemplate` from state while connecting to redux:

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form'

MainForm = connect(
    state => ({
      formValues: getFormValues('main')(state),
      initialValues: {activeTemplate: state.templates.activeTemplate}
    }),
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MainForm);
```

You can use form values selector too. Check [here](https://redux-form.com/7.0.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)

[Reference1](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/)

Comment: this throws me cannot read property 'main' of undefined in mapStateToProps function even though I can see in redux chrome extension that it is there.

Comment: You can use `getFormValues` in `mapStateToProps` too

Comment: I start getting errors at places where errors werent previously (handleSubmit is not a function at the moment). I will have to take a deeper look into it. Thank you so far, it helped me a lot anyway.

Comment: As soon as I put `initialValues` to connect() I get errors in mapStateToProps function. I used the selector for `formValues`, thats ok now. But I get undefined from `state.templates.templates` (`state.templates.activeTemplates` too). I fetch templates in `componentDidMount()` and `activeTemplate` is available in state only after the template is selected. Would you happen to know what causes the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: can you please share your reducer method, where you have initialized `templates`

Comment: I added reducer file.

Comment: I just realized that as soon as I use `state => ({
      initialValues: {activeTemplate: state.templates.activeTemplate}
    }),` , the props that I pass from the parent component are not there. That is a strange behaviour, isnt it?

Comment: Solved!! Silly mistake as usual. Typo in my reducer (`activeTemplates` instead of `activeTemplate`) and it made the whole app behave rather strange.